# I need to find EST current offset value using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I need to find current **EST offset** value using **javascript** without any server side code

Because I am hardcoding Offset value in my javascript file,i need to pass dynamically because of Day Light Saving.

Kindly Help me on that
Thanks in advance..,

Comment: Did you try `new Date().getTimezoneOffset();`?

Comment: There is only one offset for EST (presumably you mean the US Eastern Standard Time) which is -0500. The related daylight saving offset is called Eastern Daylight Time, or EDT.

Comment: @Nishant123 - That only works if the code is running on a computer set to the Eastern time zone.  If you're set to some other time zone, you can't get the current US Eastern time zone in that particular way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
var currentUSEasternTime = moment.tz('America/New_York');
var minutesOffset = currentUSEasternTime.utcOffset();    // -240
var hoursOffset = minutesOffset / 60;                    // -4
var offsetString1 = currentUSEasternTime.format('Z');    // "-04:00"
var offsetString2 = currentUSEasternTime.format('ZZ');   // "-0400"
```

Not sure what output you were looking for, so gave you a few options.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt,can you please provide the format,i need format like -4.0

Comment: You have it with `hoursOffset`.  JavaScript numbers don't distinguish between integers and decimals.